# Post on facebook fanpage within rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a problem and found several resources to solve this one, but nothing seems to work (see below for the resource).

I want a possibility to auto-Post content I save in my Rails application to a connected Facebook fanpage.
Furthermore, I don't want the user to login to Facebook within the Rails application.
Nearly all available resources are a bit cumbersome.

http://blog.bignerdranch.com/1469-how-to-update-a-facebook-page-status-using-the-facebook-api/
http://talkweb.eu/posting-to-facebook-fan-page-wall-as-an-admin-using-facebook-api/
[How to use fb_graph gem to post from app on my page wall?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847192/how-to-use-fb-graph-gem-to-post-from-app-on-my-page-wall)

I want to store some kind of token in the Rails-App which identifies the Fanpage.

Is there anything out there which does this kind of job easily?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

after nearly one day of Googling and trial and error I've found a solution for this one.

I've built a function which only needs the Facebook page_id and the Facebook page_access_token (using the koala-Gem).

```
def self.post_on_facebook(body, facebook_page_id, facebook_page_access_token)
  @user_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(facebook_page_access_token)
  page_token = @user_graph.get_page_access_token(facebook_page_id)
  @page_graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(page_token)
  @page_graph.get_connection('me', 'feed')
  @page_graph.put_wall_post(body)
end
```

This guide will enable you a way to get a non-expiring access-Token for your page.

http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/obtaining-facebook-page-access-tokens-the-4-step-program/

After doing so I can post on the pages-Wall.